# sorting dictionary in a list by value with unicode

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, unicode

I'm practicing my beautifulsoup/web scraping and have been looking at option data.  So far I have the information in a list of dictionaries.  I'm trying to sort my output by Open (in descending order) but because it is in unicode it does not sort right.  Here is a snippet of my data.

```
[{'Last': u'2.09', 'Vol': u'1', 'Open': u'200', 'Symbol': 'F', 'Strike': u'19.50', 'Ask': u'2.58', 'Date': '140816', 'Type': 'P', 'Bid': u'2.30', 'Change': u' 0.00'}, {'Last': u'1.96', 'Vol': u'1', 'Open': u'1', 'Symbol': 'F', 'Strike': u'19.50', 'Ask': u'2.60', 'Date': '140822', 'Type': 'P', 'Bid': u'2.30', 'Change': u' 0.00'}, {'Last': u'2.18', 'Vol': u'22', 'Open': u'1,045', 'Symbol': 'F', 'Strike': u'15.00', 'Ask': u'2.23', 'Date': '140816', 'Type': 'C', 'Bid': u'2.03', 'Change': u' 0.00'}]
```

What I have so far to sort is the following:

```
from operator import itemgetter
newlist = sorted(optionQuotes, key=itemgetter('Open'))
```

How would I write something in there to convert to int and then back to unicode.  Everything I've tried has failed, so I would definitely appreciate any help.

Comment: This will be tricky because e.g. `u'1,045'` would raise `ValueError` when an `int` conversion is attempted. In general, though, note that the `key` function doesn't permanently affect the contents of the dictionaries, it just creates a new value to use in the comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sorting uses lexicographic comparison, by default and you are using that to compare numbers in string format. That is why it didn't work as you expected. You can convert the value of `Open` to `int`, like this, for the comparisons used in sorting

```
sorted(optionQuotes, key=lambda x: -int(x["Open"].replace(",", "")))
```

I just replaced the `,` with empty strings, as `int` function will fail to convert strings with non-digits in them.

Also note the unary `-` operator before the result of `int` function. Since you wanted to sort in descending order, we are just negating the actual values. So, `1` will become `-1` and `1045` will become `-1045`. Now, if we sort in ascending order, `-1045` is the smallest of all the values, so it will be kept at the initial position, followed by `200` and at the last `1`.

**Edit:** As Padraic suggests in the comments, if the `Open` will have decimal numbers, you can use `float` function, instead of `int`.

Comment: If you change one of the Open Values to `2.00` what happens?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It will be the second last element, after sorting.

Comment: You have to  use `int(float())` when casting strings that are floats to ints, you cannot convert straight to int

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You are correct, but we don't know about the nature of the data, right?

Comment: Yep but comparing floats will give the correct outcome avoiding any issues where the values are decimal or not no?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham There, I included a note about that in the answer now :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted(optionQuotes, key = lambda x : float(x.get("Open").replace(",","")), reverse = True)
```

If you want to sort the list in place and avoid creating another:

```
optionQuotes.sort(key = lambda x: float(x.get("Open").replace(",","")), reverse=True)
```

Comment: How is `lambda x: x.get("Open")` any different to `itemgetter("Open")`?

Comment: @johnrsharpe, apart from not needing an import,  the op's code works, it just needs to be reversed. I did not see the point of importing to do what is needed

Comment: @PadraicCunningham He likes to sort based on the numeric value, I believe, but he is stuck with the lexicographic comparison.

Comment: @thefourtheye, ah ok I missed the  `,`

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the non digits found and convert to an int in the key function:

```
def conv(s):
    try:
        return int(''.join([e for e in s if e in u'0123456789']))
    except ValueError:
        return s    

print '\n'.join(map(str, sorted(LoD, key=lambda d: conv(d['Open']), reverse=True)))
```

Prints:

```
{'Strike': u'15.00', 'Ask': u'2.23', 'Last': u'2.18', 'Vol': u'22', 'Type': 'C', 'Symbol': 'F', 'Open': u'1,045', 'Bid': u'2.03', 'Change': u' 0.00', 'Date': '140816'}
{'Strike': u'19.50', 'Ask': u'2.58', 'Last': u'2.09', 'Vol': u'1', 'Type': 'P', 'Symbol': 'F', 'Open': u'200', 'Bid': u'2.30', 'Change': u' 0.00', 'Date': '140816'}
{'Strike': u'19.50', 'Ask': u'2.60', 'Last': u'1.96', 'Vol': u'1', 'Type': 'P', 'Symbol': 'F', 'Open': u'1', 'Bid': u'2.30', 'Change': u' 0.00', 'Date': '140822'}
```

If you want to support floats, such as in the `'Last'` field, you can use a regex so that you can support floats like `-1.23e-2`:

```
def convf(s):
    m=re.search(r'([-+]?[0-9,]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)', s)
    if not m:
        return s
    ns=re.sub(r'[^\d\.e\-+]', '', m.group(1).lower() )   
    try:
        return float(ns)
    except ValueError:
        return s        
print '\n'.join(map(str, sorted(LoD, key=lambda d: convf(d['Last']))))
```

Prints:

```
{'Strike': u'19.50', 'Ask': u'2.60', 'Last': u'1.96', 'Vol': u'1', 'Type': 'P', 'Symbol': 'F', 'Open': u'1', 'Bid': u'2.30', 'Change': u' 0.00', 'Date': '140822'}
{'Strike': u'19.50', 'Ask': u'2.58', 'Last': u'2.09', 'Vol': u'1', 'Type': 'P', 'Symbol': 'F', 'Open': u'200', 'Bid': u'2.30', 'Change': u' 0.00', 'Date': '140816'}
{'Strike': u'15.00', 'Ask': u'2.23', 'Last': u'2.18', 'Vol': u'22', 'Type': 'C', 'Symbol': 'F', 'Open': u'1,045', 'Bid': u'2.03', 'Change': u' 0.00', 'Date': '140816'}
```